# Javascript: bind arguments, but keep original ones?

Tags: javascript

I would like to inject some values to event listener's callback in JavaScript, but keeping the original event object. Is that possible?

Example (#1):

```
function callback(event, arg) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(arg);
}

var something = 2;

element.addEventListener(
    "click",
    callback.bind(element, ???, something)
);
```

How can I keep original `event` object while binding another arguments?

I know I can do this (#2):

```
element.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function (event) {
        callback(event, something);
    }
);
```

Or even this (#3):

```
element.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function (event) {
        callback(event, this);
    }.bind(something)
);
```

But #2 makes the code uglier, because I need to use variable `something` in asynchronous call, while it could have been changed at the moment of the click.

The #3 steals `this` and I might need that.

Am I missing something and/or is my understanding of binding correct?

Comment: flip the formal parameter order, then fill in from the left

Comment: you can find some libs that offer `rPartial` capabilities

Comment: While trying to solve a similar problem, I just discovered that you can omit the `event` parameter from an eventHandler, so I was able to use that as a workaround.  But that's admittedly a bit of a hack, and what to do in the other cases where that's not an option is still an important question! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "curry" the arguments you want by shifting the order of your arguments around:

```
function callback(arg, event) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(arg);
}

var something = 2;
element.addEventListener("click", callback.bind(null, something));
```

This way you pass the "bound" or partially applied as a callback and still receive an `Event` object. For more information, see the ["Partial Functions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partial_Functions) section of the the MDN [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) docs.

Comment: Are you sure? The first argument of `bind()` is what comes in place of `this`.

Comment: @RoboRobok you are absolutely right, a typo on my part. Fixed! (I've used `null` as the context since it doesn't seem to matter for your example, but feel free to substitute whatever context you need.

Comment: So basically, if I use `bind()`, any explicitly passed argument (like the `event` passed by `addEventListener`) goes to the end of the arg list? Is this how "curry" works?

Comment: Correct. Currying is another word for partial application. Essentially you are returning a function with some of the arguments supplied. Here's a quick rundown https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe

Answer (score 1):

Just make your own custom "bind" function that suits your needs. It's sort of like #2 but with the ugly abstracted away.

```
function bindLast(fn) {
    var bound = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments, 1);

    return function() {
        Array.prototype.push.apply(arguments, bound);
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Then use it like this.

```
element.addEventListener("click", bindLast(callback, something));
```

Notice you don't need to pass it a *thisArg*. It just uses the value of `this` at the time of invocation.

Comment: I could even go one step further and add bindLast to the Function prototype, but that would be quite intrusive :)